# Is there a way to run a compile all apex and triggers while validation phase?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment

We use a plugin `sfdx plugins:install sfdx-git-delta` to validate and deploy delta changes to higher org.
This has many issues and compilation issues in inevitable here if we do a delta deployment. And because of huge number of test classes we surely cannot run all tests.

Is there a command by which I can run a compile all apex class so that while validation phase only I get to know the compilation issues?

**COMPILATION ISSUE SCENARIO**

```
public class A{
    public static String getAccessToken(){
        return 'AccessToken';
    }
}
```

And this is being used by a class `B` like this `A.getAccessToken()`.

Now lets say some developer adds a parameter to `getAccessToken()` by modifying class `A` and does not change its references across codebase (Just as an example).
In this case when delta detects change only in class `A`, it deploys only class `A` and deployment will be successful.

As class `B` and other classes wont get compiled by SF automatically and thus compilation issue will occur.

Comment: I would recommend moving to use unlocked packages instead of using "happy soup" with change sets.

Comment: Why are their compilation issues? Due to what's already in the org or due to what you're deploying? There's a compile on deploy setting you can enable in sandboxes (`Setup --> Apex Settings --> Perform Synchronous Compile on Deploy`). Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves Updated my question to explain compilation issue  scenario. I will update  it here if this checkbox helps.

Comment: But I doubt it will do a full recompile of all the apex classes @KrisGoncalves

Comment: Even after enabling this `(Setup --> Apex Settings --> Perform Synchronous Compile on Deploy)` its not working with sfdx `checkonly` param, it still validates the classes successfully. May be it will validate in deploy, but deployment happens after the code gets merged, so it would be late by then as the code is already merged.

Comment: It doesn't even do that in my test - just compiles for you. If there's errors, the deployment is still successful. You won't have a way to do what you're asking. In terms of "Surely we cannot run all tests" - do you run any tests? I'd expect at some point you must decide some tests to run? You could also consider only leveraging `sfdx-git-delta` to generate an output of delta changes for everything but Apex and just include all apex for validation only deployments. Would be faster than running all tests is my guess

Comment: Exactly I ended up doing, if I detect any change in apex or triggers I am validating all the apex and triggers. And running only specified tests. For which the apex classes were changed.

Comment: Apex unit tests doesn't solve for partial lwc failures